# Swift - Enum Returning The Wrong Value Type

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums, key

I am having issues with the following code:

```
private enum Op : Printable {
    case Operand(Double)
    case Constant(String, Double)
    case Variable(String)
    case UnaryOperation(String, Double -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)
    var description: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Operand(let operand):
                return "\(operand)"
            case .Constant(let constant, _):
                return constant
            case .Variable(let variable):
                return variable
            case .UnaryOperation(let symbol, _):
                return symbol
            case .BinaryOperation(let symbol, _):
                return symbol
            }
        }
    }
}

private var knownOps = [String:Op]()

init() {
    func learnOp(op: Op) {
        knownOps[op.description] = op
    }
    learnOp(Op.Constant("π", M_PI))
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation("√", sqrt))
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation("sin", sin))
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation("cos", cos))
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation("±") { -1 * $0 })
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("×", *))
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("÷") { $1 / $0 })
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("+", +))
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("-") { $1 - $0 })
}
```

After the init() is complete, the dictionary `knownOps` contains the following:

```
knownOps    [String : Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op]    9 key/value pairs   
[0] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "×" 
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   Operand Operand
[1] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "+" 
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   Operand Operand
[2] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "÷" 
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   Operand Operand
[3] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "π" 
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   Constant    Constant
[4] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "-" 
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   Operand Operand
[5] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "±" 
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   UnaryOperation  UnaryOperation
[6] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "sin"   
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   UnaryOperation  UnaryOperation
[7] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "√" 
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   UnaryOperation  UnaryOperation
[8] _DictionaryElement<String, Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op>       
key String  "cos"   
value   Calculator.CalculatorModel.Op   UnaryOperation  UnaryOperation
```

My question is: why are the `binaryOperation`s being captured as `Operand`s in the dictionary?

Comment: How do you check the contents of `knownOps`?  Via debugger?  Or printing it out?

Comment: I checked it via the debugger in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following variable to your enum:

```
var type: String {
    get {
        switch self {
        case .Operand:
            return "Operand"
        case .Constant:
            return "Constant"
        case .Variable:
            return "Variable"
        case .UnaryOperation:
            return "UnaryOperation"
        case .BinaryOperation:
            return "BinaryOperation"
        }
    }
}
```

Then looped through the dict with the following code:

```
for (key, value) in knownOps
{
    let valueType = value.type
    println("\(key) : \(valueType)")
}
```

This gave me the output:

```
× : BinaryOperation
+ : BinaryOperation
÷ : BinaryOperation
π : Constant
- : BinaryOperation
± : UniaryOperation
sin : UniaryOperation
√ : UniaryOperation
cos : UniaryOperation
```

So I guess the answer to your questions is that it isn't. I can't offer an answer as to why the debugger or whatever you used to inspect the values was incorrect, but the code you posted isn't wrong.

Comment: I implemented the same code and received the same result. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I managed to reproduce what you say in your question.  If I run the thing in debug mode in Xcode 6.4, put a breakpoint, and inspect the contents of `knownOps`, then indeed I see binary operations stored as just an operand.

What I think is happening is Swift compiler optimisation coupled with a bug.

Reasons I think so are:

- Similar code (just ported) to Xcode 7 beta renders `enum` in `knownOps` as `Invalid`.
- If I "inspect" contents of `knownOps` by printing them out (e.g. in a for-loop) then everything is printed out just as expected, both in Xcode 6.4 and in Xcode 7 beta.
- If I trace the execution of code that prints out the contents of `knownOps` by stepping into instructions, then I do not see anything that looks like: 1) check out the value stored by `enum` property, and then 2) based on property's value, decide what to return as `description` computed property of the `enum`.

Therefore, most likely your code is simple enough for the compiler to be able to "predict" what has to be printed out or what the execution path should look like, to just throw all "unnecessary" stuff out.  And probably the debugger in 6.4 is simply not up to speed with this thing..

But good news is that debugger from Xcode 7 "knows" about this.  It says `invalid` instead of feeding you with a bogus.

Comment: Excellent answer. Your reasoning led me to stop focusing on this error and find the bug in the other part of the software (as tiny as it was!).